# Let $f:(0, +\infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a continuous function. Suppose $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}f(x) = \lim_{x \rightarrow +\infty} f(x)= +\infty$.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, optimization

Suppose $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}f(x) = \lim_{x \rightarrow +\infty} f(x)= +\infty$.
Then $f$ has a global minimum.

**My attempt**

Let $y>0$.

Since $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}f(x) = +\infty$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that
$0<x<\delta \Rightarrow f(x)>f(y).$  And since $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}f(x) = +\infty$, there exists $M>0$ such that
$x>M \Rightarrow f(x)>f(y).$

Thus $f$ has global minimum in $(0, \infty)$ iif $f$ has a minimum in $[\delta, M]$. By The Weierstrass extreme value theorem, $f$ has global minimum in $[\delta, M]$ since $f$ is continuous. Then $f$ has global minimum.

Am I right?

Comment: You are right !